# Override = operator linked linked c++ deep copy

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-keyword

So, I'm trying override operator= in a linked list class I'm writing, but keep getting this weird problem for some reason.

```
List& List::operator=(const List& copyList){
if(copyList.head != nullptr){
    makeEmpty();   // clears *this from any previous nodes
    cout << "if statement " << endl;
    head = new Node; // create a new node for head
    head -> data = copyList.head -> data; // copy the first data of copylist
    Node* pnew = head; // a temp node to traverse the new linkedlist
    assert(head != nullptr);
    Node* current2 = copyList.head;
    current2 = current2 -> next;
    while(current2 != NULL && pnew != NULL){
        cout << "entering while loop " << endl;
        pnew-> next = new Node;
        pnew -> next->data = current2 ->data;
        cout << "pnew next data " << *(pnew -> next->data)  << endl;
        assert(pnew-> next != nullptr);
        pnew = pnew -> next;
        current2 = current2 -> next;
        cout << "after current2" << endl;
    }
     pnew -> next = NULL;

}else{
    cout << "else statement " << endl;
    head = nullptr;
}
cout<< "printing out copylist"<< endl << copyList << endl;
cout<< "printing current list: " << endl << *this << endl;
return *this;
```

}

So, this is the code I have to test the operator override:

```
cout << "mylist:" << endl << mylist << endl;
   cout << "mylist4:" << endl << mylist4 << endl;
   mylist = mylist4;
   cout << "mylist:" << endl;
   cout << mylist << endl;
   cout << "mylist4:" << endl;
   cout << mylist4 << endl;
```

This is the output:

```
mylist:
10 f
16 u
20 n
25 !

mylist4:
14 s
15 t
16 u
18 f
19 f
25 !

if statement
entering while loop
pnew next data 15 t

after current2
entering while loop
pnew next data 16 u

after current2
entering while loop
pnew next data 18 f

after current2
entering while loop
pnew next data 19 f

after current2
entering while loop
pnew next data 25 !

after current2
printing out copylist
14 s
15 t
16 u
18 f
19 f
25 !

printing current list:
14 s
15 t
16 u
18 f
19 f
25 !
*crashes right here*
```

I have been trying to figure out this problem for about 3 days. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here are the constructor (the destructor is the default one by the compiler):

```
NodeData::NodeData(int n, char c)  { 
    num = n; ch = c; 
}
```

EDIT2: I found the problem after careful examination. The problem was that I did not point the last node of head, pnew after the while loop, to null. This fixed the issue. Thanks to all your support.

Comment: You don't get that output with the posted code. Reason first and foremost, it won't even ***compile***. There is no `if` matching that `else`, and there are at least two *major* logic issues I see in this code alone, which doesn't hold out much hope for the rest of your list.

Comment: Oh, sorry man. I edited it. Accidentally, left out the if statement.

Comment: @EdHeal judging by the comment to Dietmar's answer, this is an academic exercise.

Comment: If you use the compiler's default constructor, your list will leak memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have control over your Node class, and it should support copy-construction and assignment operators either transparently or if needed by your own hand. Given that, I concur with Dietmar that utilizing the copy-ctor/swap/destructor mechanics is the ideal approach.

If you insist on doing this by-hand the following is one way to do it. Your implementation is making this *much* harder than it needs to be.

```
List& List::operator=(const List& copyList)
{
    List tmp;
    Node **dst = &tmp.head;
    const Node* src = copyList.head;
    while (src)
    {
        *dst = new Node(*src);     // invoke Node copy-ctor
        src = src->next;           // advance source
        (*dst)->next = nullptr;    // break link to original next
        dst = &(*dst)->next;       // move target to next pointer
    }

    // tmp now has a copy of the source list
    //  swap its head pointer with ours.
    std::swap(tmp.head, head);

    // upon return, the tmp object that now holds our
    //  original list will clean it up. we own the
    //  new list form this point on. 
    return *this;
}
```

**How It Works**

The pointer-to-pointer `dst` always holds the address of the next pointer to be populated with a new node. Initially it holds the address of the local `List tmp` object's head pointer. . As we add nodes it is updated to always hold the address of the `next` pointer of the last-node-added. By doing this we get forward-chaining automatically. Once we're done copying, `tmp` is now a duplicate of the source. We then swap head pointer with own own. This in turn swaps who owns which list. When `tmp` is destroyed on function-exit it will destroy our old list with it. We keep the new list, pointed to by our `head` pointer.

The above assumes you're using the default copy-ctor of `Node`, which means making a copy will copy both the data value *and* the next link, the latter you do NOT want, thus the embedded link-break. If you actually implement `Node::Node(const Node&)` to always set the link to NULL after the copy the link-break can be eliminated. I.e., your `Node` copy-constructor should look something like this:

```
Node::Node(const Node& arg)
    : data(arg.data)
    , next()
{
}
```

This ensures a clean(as clean as `data` can be copied, anyway) copy with no accidental link to the original `arg` next pointer.

All of that said, Dietmar's answer is the most-correct, and I've up voted it accordingly. If this helps you, consider up-voting it, but his is easily the ideal solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. This somewhat helped me get a sense of what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I'd upvote it if the code would first copy the list abd then get rid of the original one! The pointer to pointer to next trick is neat. The code is roughly what the copy constructor should do, though...

Comment: @DietmarKühl yeah, I considered just doing that. The only reason I left it as-is/was is the drop-in functionality for the OP. but I completely concur in the by-value copy/swap idiom you put forth. It really is the right approach. If I get some time I'll amend it to this answer. The pointer-to-pointer is *extremely* useful for things like list/tree insertions, etc. I use it often in C code. And thanks for the review. Always welcome.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to change it to use the copy constructor but to fix the exception safety problem: the assignment should be stringly exception-safe.

Comment: @DietmarKühl If you mean in the event the allocation and construction of `Node` tossed an exception you're quite correct. As written it will result in only a partial list and the original will be destroyed, to be sure. The partial would be properly terminated, but that isn't much help. If there was something else I'm likely not seeing it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl ok. I *think* that was what you were getting at. Or hopefully close to it, anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes, this solves the exception-safety problem, too.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking to hard at the implementation (I stopped when I spotted `makeEmpty()` which makes sure that the assignment operator won't be strongly exception-safe without any good reason): the easiest way to implement an assignment operator is to leverage the copy constructor, the destructor, and a generally trivial to write `swap()` funciton. The implementation look the same for all classes except for the class name:

```
T& T::operator= (T other) {
    other.swap(this);
    return *this;
}
```

Note, it *is* deliberate to pass the argument by value: this is where the value is actually happening. Compared to copying by `T const&` it has the advantage the actual copy can be elided in some cases.

Comment: How can I do know that T always has the method swap()? I mean, for the assignment we are giving, they do not have swap methods nor copy constructors; we cannot add methods to NodeData.

Comment: @user2922605: You don't `swap()` some node data! You call `swap()` for the class you are implementing and if it doesn't have such a method, you implement it! Likewise with the copy constructor: your list surely has a copy constructor!

Comment: @DietmarKühl Except you implemented move not copy, and he was clearly trying to implement copy. If he does 'list1 = list2' you would not expect them to swap but your impl does.

Comment: @kfsone The copy is in the **by-value** parameter. He's then simply swapping content (including the head pointers) from one `List` object to the other. This exchanges ownership of the lists. When `other` is destroyed it takes out the old list and the new list now belongs to `this`. This requires a proper copy-ctor, but you should have that regardless (or at least you better). A partial implementation of this is in my updated answer, manually making the copy in a local rather than the operator doing it in a by-val-parameter.

Comment: @kfsone: I'm indeed moving the argument which the assignment got passed. However, the argument is passed by value, i.e., it is copied from the right hand side of the assignment! The assignment ever only sees a specifically created temporary object which is fine to move from. The primary reason for this approach is that the copy can sometimes be elided entirely.