# operator= overload for Linked List issues

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I'm having issues with my implementation of the overloaded = operator for a linked list. The List class contains a `Node* head` pointer and a `struct Node` containing `T* data` and `Node* next`, where T is a template typename. I'm having trouble with what is happening at the end of the operator function where the destructor (in this case handled by `makeEmpty`) is being called twice by the end of the operator, once after iterating through the list and creating a new list of the same nodes and once after the operator function exits.

Here is the makeEmpty implementation:

```
// Does the work of the Destructor
template <typename T>
void List<T>::makeEmpty() {

cout << endl << endl << "DESTRUCTOR CALLED" << endl << endl;
List<T>::Node* tempPtr = head;

if (head != NULL) {

    List<T>::Node* nextPtr = head->next;

    for(;;) {
        if (tempPtr != NULL) {

            delete tempPtr->data;
            tempPtr = nextPtr;

            if (nextPtr != NULL)
                nextPtr = nextPtr->next;

            /*tempPtr = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = tempPtr;*/
        }

        else break;
    }
}

}
```

Here is the operator= overload implementation:

```
// Overloaded to be able to assign one list to another
template <typename T>
List<T> List<T>::operator=(const List& listToCopy) {

List<T> listToReturn;
listToReturn.head = NULL;
List<T>::Node* copyPtr = listToCopy.head;

List<T>::Node* thisPtr = head;

if (copyPtr != NULL && thisPtr != NULL) {
    for(;;) {
        if (copyPtr != NULL) {

            T* toInsert = new T(*copyPtr->data);
            listToReturn.insert(toInsert);

            copyPtr = copyPtr->next;
        }

        else{cout << endl << listToReturn << endl << endl; return listToReturn;}
    }
}
// if right-hand list is NULL, return an empty list
return listToReturn;
}
```

I've been debugging for a little bit and it seems that the second time the destructor is called, the head of the list being destroyed contains unreadable memory. I'm not even sure why the destructor is being called twice within the operator since the only list that needs to be destroyed is the listToReturn after it has been returned. (maybe my logic is flawed somewhere... I've just been thinking about this for too long)

If you guys need anymore info about the code, I'd be glad to provide. As usual, this is for an assignment, so I'm only asking for tips that may help me get in the right direction. So thanks to everyone for looking and helping!

Comment: You and [this questioner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610604/override-operator-linked-linked-c-deep-copy) really need to get together. And include the *full* template class declaration of `List` in your question. I can see already you have one level of dynamic allocation you do not need. There is no reason at all for `List<T>::Node::data` to be dynamic, unless you can think of a good reason to allocate a `Node` without data (and there isn't one, btw).

Comment: You should return `List<T>&` in the assignment operator

Answer (score 4):

You asked for pointers and tips, so I'm giving it:

**1) Unnecessary dynamic data member**

Your `List<T>::Node` does *not* need a dynamic member for the underlying data value. It should be constructible from a `const T&` and if implementing a C++11-compliant move-construction idiom, a `T&&` as well. And *both* should initialize the `next` member to `nullptr`

**2) Copy-constructor for `List<T>` is *mandetory***

In accordance with the [Rules of Three, Four, or Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), your class has dynamic members, and as such must properly manage them in a copy-construction and assignment operator action (or hide said implementations, but clearly that isn't an option for you, as it is part of your assignment).

**3) Utilize the class copy-constructor for the assignment operator overload**

Overloading an assignment operator where dynamic allocations are involved (and they are here, as your linked list of `Node` mandates it) should ideally utilize the copy-constructor and the copy/swap idiom for lifetime management. This has a number of benefits, the two most important being potentially eliding the copy-operation by an optimizing compiler, and exception safety that maintains objects in their original state.

**4) The `List<T>::operator =` override should return a reference to the current object**

The current object being *assigned-to* (the left side of the operator) should be a by-reference return result. It should be the object that is modified. This is part and parcel with the standard implementation for such an operator. You return a copy, but the original object remains untouched, thereby utterly defeating the purpose of the assignment operator (i.e. the lvalue side isn't actually modified in your implementation at all)

Each of these is addressed in detail below:

---

**Unnecessary dynamic data member**

As it is not posted, I must be somewhat soothsaying in what `List` looks like. I imagine something like this:

```
template<class T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T* data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node *head;

    // other members and decls...
};
```

With this your insertion and copy operations are having to take significant advantages to manage dynamic allocations of `T` objects where they shouldn't need to. `List<T>` should certainly own a chain of `Node`; but `Node` should own the actual `T` object, and be responsible for managing it therein; *not* `List<T>`. Consider this instead:

```
template<class T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;

        Node(const T& arg) 
            : data(arg), next()
        {}

        Node(const Node& arg)
            : data(arg.data), next()
        {}

    private:
        // should never be called, and therefore hidden. A
        // C++11 compliant toolchain can use the `delete` declarator.
        Node& operator =(const Node&);
    };
    Node *head;

    // other members and decls...
};
```

Now when a new node is needed to hold a `T` object (such as in an insertion operation) the following can be done:

```
template<typename T>
void List<T>::someFunction(const T& obj)
{ 
    Node *p = new Node(obj);
    // ...use p somewhere...
}
```

---

**Copy-constructor for `List<T>` is *mandetory***

Your linked list, by its very nature, manages a dynamic chain. Therefore this class *must* implement copy-construction and assignment operations, the latter being part of your assignment and the reason you posted your question. Duplicating a linked list is fairly straight-forward, but some, for whatever reason, make it harder than it seems. The following is one of my preferred ways of doing it:

```
template<typename T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& arg)
    : head()
{
    Node **dst = &head;
    const Node* src = arg.head;
    while (src)
    {
        *dst = new Node(*src);     // invoke Node copy-construction
        dst = &(*dst)->next;       // move target to new node's next pointer
        src = src->next;           // advance source
    }
}
```

This uses a simple technique of a pointer-to-pointer to hold the *address* of the pointer being populated with the next new node. Initially it holds the address of our head pointer. With each new node added it is advanced to hold the address of the newly added node's `next` member. Since `Node(const Node&)` already sets `next` to `nullptr` (see prior section) our list is always terminated properly.

---

**Utilize the class copy-constructor for the assignment operator overload**

**The `List<T>::operator =` override should return a reference to the current object**

Once we have a solid copy constructor, we can use it for overriding our assignment operator. This is done in a not-so-apparent way, but I'll explain after the code:

```
template<typename T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(List<T> byval)
{
    std::swap(head, byval.head); // we get his list; he gets ours
    return *this;
}
```

I'm sure you're looking at this and thinking, "Huh??". It deserves some explanation. Look carefully at the parameter `byval` being passed in, and consider why I named it as I did. It is *not* a traditional `const` reference you're likely used to seeing. It is value *copy* of the right-hand-side of the assignment expression. Thus, to create it the compiler will generate a new `List<T>`, invoking the copy-constructor to do so. The result of that copy is the temporary object `byval` we have as our parameter. All we do is exchange head pointers. Think about what that does. By exchanging head pointers we take his list and he takes ours. But his was a copy of the original right-side of the assignment expression, and ours, well, we want it deleted. And that is exactly what will happen when the *destructor* for `byval` is fired once this function is finished.

In short it makes code like this:

```
List<int> lst1, lst2;
lst1.insert(1);
lst2.insert(2);
lst1 = lst2; // <== this line
```

execute our function on the marked line. That function will make a *copy* of `lst2`, passing it into the assignment operator where `lst1` will exchange head pointers with the temporary copy. The result will be `lst1`'s old node will be cleaned up by the destructor of `byval`, and the new node list is properly in place.

There are a number of reasons to do this. First, it makes your assignment operator exception-safe. If an exception is tossed (usually a memory allocation exception, but it doesn't matter) no memory is leaked, and the original object `lst1` remains in its original state. Second, the compiler can elide this away entirely if it chooses and the conditions are correct.

Anyway, these are some ideas and some points of bugs in your implementation. I hope you find them useful.